# Check is [wildcard] Folder exist and set is as variable

Tags: powershell, variables, directory, pwd

I have this bellow command to check is folder contains name "AAA_*" in path "C:\Test" exist and if so - make from it name variable:

```
$DirPath = "C:\Test"
$DirName = "AAA"
If (Test-Path -Path ($DirPath + "\" + $DirName + "_*")) {                                               
C:;cd\;cd ($DirPath + "\" + $DirName + "_*")
$NameFromDir = pwd | Select-Object | %{$_.ProviderPath.Split("\")[-1]}
cd $PSScriptRoot}
```

I have to double write it path, and also i need to go to inside of it to set is as variable.

Is this can be done in another shorten or easier way?

Comment: `$NameFromDir = (Get-ChildItem C:\Test\AAA_*).Name`?

Comment: How could the folder name contain `*` ? That's not an allowed character in Windows

Comment: @mklement0
This command is very short and fine. Just need to change it little bit, because .Name get me whole path (eg. C:\Test\AAA_BBB), and I was needed only name (AAA_BBB). 
So I finally used: **$NameFromDir = (Get-ChildItem C:\Test\AAA_*).Basename** Anyway -  Thanks again for your help!  :)

Comment: Glad to hear it, @MikeZetPL, but note that `.Name` is only ever the file or directory _name_, not a full path (only `.FullName` is); for _directories_, `.BaseName` is the same as `.Name` (for _files_, it is the name with the extension removed).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this ($NameFromDir will be empty if path does not exist):

```
$DirPath = "C:\Test"
$DirName = "AAA"
$NameFromDir = (Get-Item "$DirPath\$DirName_*").FullName
```

If you need to restrict the result to a single element you can add

```
| select-object -First 1
```

Comment: Thanks also for your command - its also working version, and FullName need to be changed to Basename - then I will get only foldername without full path:
**$NameFromDir = (Get-Item "$DirPath\$DirName_*").Basename**